# Avoiding repetition in multiple commands in Ansible task list

Tags: ansible

I have a task file with a lot of repetition. Each of these shell commands tend to require working within a virtual environment, within a specific working directory, and under a specific user. For example, my tasks tend to look like this:

```
- name: Build thing
  shell: source ~/project/venv/bin/activate; ./thing build chdir=~/project
  sudo_user: "{{ thing_user }}"

- name: Register thing
  shell: source ~/project/venv/bin/activate; ./thing register chdir=~/project
  sudo_user: "{{ thing_user }}"
```

Is there any way I can avoid repeating myself at the task level? Ideally, I could declare working directory, virtual environments, and sudo_users once. This is hard for me to do at the role or playbook level.

Answer (score 2):

Since the only difference between them is the command you could use [Loops](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html) so it would become

```
- name: Build thing
  shell: source ~/project/venv/bin/activate; ./thing {{ item }} chdir=~/project
  sudo_user: "{{ thing_user }}"
  with_items:
    - build
    - register
```